# why does openpyxl keeps changing "normal" formula into an array formula

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

So I have a table with the following formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((IFERROR(INDEX(Tabela2[start],MATCH(((Tabela1[type]=J3) *  Tabela1[id]),Tabela2[id],0))>=$I$1;0)*1))
```

which just count the number of entries that happen after a certain date and are of a certain type

however when I run my script which uses `openpyxl` to update the main table , it adds curly brackets to the previous formula which makes it return the wrong values. I can fix it by just enter it normally without **control+shift+center** but it is kind of annoying having to fix it every time I update it

I also made the following script that just opens and saves the files and it also adds curly brackets to the formula. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

ficheiro = 'Livro1.xlsx'
workbook = load_workbook(filename=ficheiro)
workbook.save(filename="test1 -test.xlsx")
```

Comment: It's not openpyxl doing anything but Excel, presumably because of the type of formula.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to prevent excel from doing that? Because the formula is working before  I run the script, excel should just keep the way it was.

Answer (score 0):

"...it adds curly brackets to the formula. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong."

It's Excel's dynamic array function added with Office 365 compatibility and certain cross-platform updates. It assumes the formula is an array and forces curly braces ("{", "}") unless one uses an implicit intersection operator ("@").  The down side is that older versions of Excel don't recognize either operator and will cause string variables (lookup, parse, filter, concatenate "&") to crash in VBA code.

There is no way to prevent excel from doing that, but this may be a useful workaround.

This code removes the implicit intersection after inserting the '@' operator to force turning off the dynamic array function while executing VBA.  This cycles thru each worksheet and returns to the original sheet. Comment out the formula list to suit particular use of the formulas causing difficulty. The second macro changes type of replace function used depending on version VBA by testing if it recognizes newer array constructs. The trick is to use a precompile identifier (#) to process newer code that the retro editor will not allow but also in which the newer formulas won't work without.

```
Sub DelOperand

Scheat = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets(1).Select
For Count = 1 To Worksheets.Count

   'Remove forced special character'
    Run FormulaFix("Cell")
    Run FormulaFix("Column")
    Run FormulaFix("FilterXML")
    Run FormulaFix("FormulaText")
   'Run FormulaFix("Frequency")'
   'Run FormulaFix("Growth")'
    Run FormulaFix("Hyperlink")
    Run FormulaFix("If")
    Run FormulaFix("Index")
    Run FormulaFix("Indirect")
    Run FormulaFix("IsFormula")
   'Run FormulaFix("LinEst")'
   'Run FormulaFix("LogEst")'
   'Run FormulaFix("MInverse")'
   'Run FormulaFix("MMult")'
   'Run FormulaFix("Mode.MULT")'
   'Run FormulaFix("Munit")'
    Run FormulaFix("Offset")
    Run FormulaFix("Row")
    Run FormulaFix("Transpose")
   'Run FormulaFix("Trend")'

    If Count = Worksheets.Count Then Exit For
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Next

Sheets(Scheat).Select
Err.Clear

End Sub


Function FormulaFix(ByRef Whatzit)
'Credit: Stephen L. Rush'

Dim WhatNow
Dim ErrNum As Integer

On Error Resume Next

WhatNow = "@" & Whatzit

If Application.Evaluate("=XLOOKUP(1,{1,2,3},{3,2,1})") Then
   #If Not Err = 0 Then
    Cells.Replace What:=WhatNow, Replacement:=Whatzit, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
   #Else
    Cells.Replace What:=WhatNow, Replacement:=Whatzit, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
   #End If
End If
Next

On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```