# python panda ExcelWriter switching dynamic formula to array formula

Tags: python, pandas, excel, pandas.excelwriter

### Context

I queried some data as `pd.dataframe` from db and save it with `pd.ExcelWriter` in xlsx.writer engine to  a formatted xlsx template.
The saved data is then referenced in another sheet by dynamic formula and other formulas.

### Problem

In the excel, there are two sheets : "Raw Data" and "Format Data":
"Raw Data" Stores the fetched data, "Format Data" contains the formula and reference cells from "Raw Data"

After the ExcelWriter processed the excel file, the dynamic formula in "Processed Data" changed to array formula, which denied the formula to expand. For example, there is a formula:
`=FILTER(UNIQUE('Raw Data'!$I$4:$I$2000),UNIQUE('Raw Data'!$I$4:$I$2000)<>0)`
which should return all unique data from I4:I2000.

However, the excel after ExcelWriter process changed the dynamic formula to array formula in range I4:I400 as the original template only have 396 unique values. Even if the updated data source have more than 396 unique values, it could only display 396 items.

It would be nice if someone could kindly advise the cause of this issue and provide a solution to stop the change of the dynamic formulas.

*Remarks: I am trying not to do the data processing with python so please don't comment on that.*

### Code Snippet FYR

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists="overlay",)
    for config in excelUpdateConfigs:
        result = fetchSQL(db_conn, config["sql"])
        result = result.astype(config["dtype"])
        result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Raw Data", float_format="%.5f", startrow=2, startcol=config["startcol"], header=True, index=False, engine="io.excel.xlsx.writer")
writer.close()
```

### **What I have tried**

I have tried to do some research online but I can't see any related articles about dynamic formula right now.
I doubt that the low level logic of ExcelWriter is creating a new excel file based on the given path instead of editing on top of it so it breaks some of the equations and inserted items. Please advise if I'm wrong.

Comment: Is it possible for you to paste `result` in your code snippet using this [Markdown Tool](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)

Comment: @rachel there are more than 100 queries each with different format, one of them that the problem exists is in the following format {Date:dbdate, StockAbbr:str, ClosePrice:float64}

Comment: Just to clarify, `result` is data frame for "Raw Data" sheet, `result.to_excel` never touches `Format Data` sheet. but after `result.to_excel` is executed, `FILTER` formula in `Format Data` sheet is changed?

Comment: @rachel That is correct.

Comment: I tried put 400 random numbers in `result` and run your code snippet. I saw `FILTER` function has curly bracket wrapped around it. I managed to fix it by input `FILTER` as an array formula in the first place. that is, select `A1:A2000` in "Format Data", input `=FILTER(UNIQUE('Raw Data'!$I$4:$I$2000),UNIQUE('Raw Data'!$I$4:$I$2000)<>0)` in formula bar, press Ctrl + Shift + Enter. (According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373560/why-does-openpyxl-keeps-changing-normal-formula-into-an-array-formula, it has nothing to do with openpyxl, but it has something to do with excel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem using below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

excel_path = 'test.xlsx'

data = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=400)

result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['close'])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists="overlay",)
result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Raw Data", float_format="%.5f", startrow=2, startcol=8, header=True, index=False, engine="io.excel.xlsx.writer")
writer.close()
```

test.xlsx has two tabs: "Raw Data", "Format Data".
In format data cell A1, I input below

`=FILTER(UNIQUE('Raw Data'!$I$4:$I$2000),UNIQUE('Raw Data'!$I$4:$I$2000)<>0)`

After running the code, I saw filter function changed to this:
[image]

So I decided to change the way `FILTER` is applied in "Format Data" sheet in the first place, that is, select `A1:A2000` in "Format Data", input `=FILTER(UNIQUE('Raw Data'!$I$4:$I$2000),UNIQUE('Raw Data'!$I$4:$I$2000)<>0)` in formula bar, press Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

This way openpyxl won't change it, and it will always accommodate 2000 datapoints.

Comment: Thank you rachel for the answer. In this case, I would say there's no solution to conserve dynamic formula. However, I am quite happy with the alternatives. Hope this helps others that encountered the same issue. Cheers.